# How can I find the height of a tree in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

Define a Scheme procedure (tree-height t) that calculates the height of a non-empty
tree t

```
(define (height tree)
  (if (null? tree)
      0
      (max (height (caddr tree)))))

'(5(1(8)(2(1)(9)))(10)(4(9)))
```

Should return 4

Comment: DIsregard this, solved it :P. I forgot +1

Comment: You can post your solution as a response to the question then if you feel that other people will have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you forgot to add 1 to the answer, but you also forgot to take the max of the `cadr` and the `caddr`, you just found the max of the `caddr`.  You could have a tree whose left branch is larger than the right branch, but your program would return the height of the right branch, and incorrect answer.  This code should solve your problem.

```
(define (height tree)
  (if (null? tree)
        0
        (+ 1 (max (height (cadr tree)) 
                  (height (caddr tree))))))
```